# Java: Trying to make a reset button, but it just makes duplicates of the program

Tags: java, button, reset

So, I have been working on a reset button and I need help because currently the program just creates an extra copy of itself when I need it to replace the old one instead of adding to it. (This is a java quiz game, btw)

Here is a link to the all of the code https://gist.github.com/anonymous/522b2a89ba2fc6750d2e

here is the code that I specifically need help with:

```
        if(src.equals(restart)){
        quiz.showRestartSummary();
        //quiz.restart(); not important right now
        JavaQuiz quiz2=new JavaQuiz();
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your issue is that you're creating new instances of your Quiz without disposing of the current Quiz in execution.

I Added the line below to your restart() method in your JavaQuiz class, it will close the previous jframe created:

```
  this.dispose();
```

Also

You can dispatch a windowClosing Event to the jframe, like below:

```
this.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(this, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
```

Make the change below:

```
public void restart(){
      //wrongs=0;
      //total=0;
      // Change should be made here.
     this.dispose();
    }
```